# Missing Jacoco Code Coverage and IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian, jacoco-maven-plugin, arquillian-drone

I have a maven project with some Arquillian Tests (Drone/Graphene Tests included).

When I build my project using maven all my Arquillian Tests that use Graphene and Drone or Warp will fail with following exception

```
Running de.mmo.arq.model.diverses.stammdaten.geldinstitut.GeldinstitutBlzTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.862 sec <<< FAILURE! - in de.mmo.arq.model.diverses.stammdaten.geldinstitut.GeldinstitutBlzTest
de.mmo.arq.model.diverses.stammdaten.geldinstitut.GeldinstitutBlzTest  Time elapsed: 4.862 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ArchiveExportException: Failed to write asset to output: /WEB-INF/classes/de/mmo/base/dao/CrudService.class
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.jacoco.core.internal.flow.ClassProbesVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

This is the place where the magic should happen

```
<build>
    <finalName>browser</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagBase>...</tagBase>
                <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jacoco</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.jacoco.core</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>arq-wildfly</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.surefire}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <arquillian.launch>wildfly-remote</arquillian.launch>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.surefire}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${wildfly.maven-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I'm using mvn to build my project with this goals ***clean package -fae*** with this profiles ***jacoco arq-wildfly***

The build fails and the jacoco.exec file is created at my target directory.

If I remove the goal **prepare-agent** in the jacoco profile and run the same mvn command (**clean package -fae**) with the profiles **jacoco arq-wildfly** all my tests finish successfull but without creating the jacoco.exec file.

What I'm doing wrong? Does someone have a working example using Arquillian with Drone/Graphene Tests and Jacoco for code coverage?

For additional information about my environment:

- Wildfly 10
- Arquillian Core 1.1.11.Final
- Arquillian Drone 1.3.1.Final
- Arquillian Graphene 2.1.0.Beta1
- Arquillian Jacoco 1.0.0.Alpha8
- Jacoco 0.7.6.201602180812

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a multiple asm versions on your classpath, jacoco needs the most recent one.

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to find the asm versions, I think you have **asm:asm** and **org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all** in your dependencies.

Exclude the old version (asm:asm) with the following for the dependency which needs asm:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

For drone it would be something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```